# .addEventListener doesnt work, any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I tried it with "click" it worked, I also tried e.keycode, that didn't seem to have any effect.

```
  window.onload = function() {
    c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    cc = c.getContext("2d");
    setInterval(update, 1000 / 30);
  };
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var cacX1 = 960
  var dy = document.getElementById("myCanvas").height - 60
  var speed = -1
  var drop = -7

  function update() {
    //  drawBack();
    //  drawCac();
    drawDino();
  };

  c.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (dy >= c.height - 70) {
      dy = 10
      drawDino();
      console.log("up");
    }
  }, false);


  function drawDino() {
    cc.fillStyle = "white";
    cc.fillRect(30, dy, 30, 50);
    if (dy < document.getElementById("myCanvas").height - 60) {
      dy = dy - drop
      console.log("dropping" + drop);
    }
  };
```

I'm sorry for asking such noobish question, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: You should probably indent your code.

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Either `window.onload = ...` is unnecessary or `dy` is `NaN` and `c.addEventListener(...)` throws a `TypeError`

Comment: Also you have both missing and unnecessary semicolons. Here's a gist with the code properly indented and semicolons fixed: https://gist.github.com/sh78/8c52b61f6bbbfa02dcd0f71124112bd1

Comment: @SLaks console shows nothing relevant

Comment: `var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");` will only work as you expect if that script is below your `<canvas>`.

Comment: @ChrisG It is below.

Comment: @Andreas in the console there is no error
I logged dy and it has a value.